# Why I can not use resteasy-jackson2-provider and resteasy-multipart-provider at the same time?

Tags: java, rest, api

I have an application where I use API to get some data(method POST) and after that, i use the data, and I need to send multipart PUT back. But if i had dependency to resteasy-jackson2-provider and resteasy-multipart-provider the app can not build (only if i use different versions) and after build the app fall.(It is not important) The methods work separeted, but not together. Some tips how to use dependency together or how to one of them replace?

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.11.Final</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.11.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.11.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-multipart-provider -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.11.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

This is not a right solution. Because works the first choice.